# Cannot use a backslash in a replacement string with String.replaceFirst() or String.replaceAll()

Tags: java

I am attempting to replace a part of a string with a backslash.

I can do this with the `.replace()` method, but attempting the same with `.replaceAll()` or `.replaceFirst()` causes an error.

Here's the code I'm using, which I've pushed to a [replit](https://repl.it/@ericandrewlewis/MaroonSeparateExam):

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "hello world";
    a = a.replaceFirst("h", "H");
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(a.replace("o", "\\"));
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll("w", "\\"));
    System.out.println(a.replaceFirst("e", "\\"));
  }
}
```

and here's the output with an error:

```
Hello world
Hell\ w\rld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:809)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:955)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
exit status 1
```

Comment: This works but I don't  why backslash doesn't work in replaceAll or replaceFirst:

a = "hello";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("h");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);
a = matcher.replaceFirst(matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"));

Comment: Use \\\\ for a literal backslash.  Then it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll` does a regex match, and a regex based replacement.

A regex replace string can contain references to the search regex in the form of `\0` (or `\\0` if encoded as a String.

Your program is giving an error because it expects a \ followed by a number, but the number is missing. Use `\\` (or in your case `\\\\`, since in your case you encode it in a string)

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you use `"\\"` : The first `\` will escape the second one. Then the `h` in hello will be replace by `\`. Your String now values `"\ello"`. And when you print this string, the `\` is interpreted and escape the `e` (which done nothing since `e` is not a special char), so you obtain `ello`.

When you use `"\\\\"` : The first `\` escpaes the second, and the third escape the fourth. Then the `h` is replace by `\\`. Your string now values `"\\ello"`. And when you print this, the first `\` escapes the second one, so you obtain `\ello`

Answer (score -1):

Just write System.out.println(a.replace("o", "\\\\")) and not System.out.println(a.replace("o", "\\"));

Have fun.